# Как изменить цвет текста легенды датасетов в графике Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Использую Chart.js. Сам код графика на js. Нужно изменить цвет текста датасетов.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать ?

Команды color, итд связанные с цветом текста не принимает в options -> plugins -> legend. Зато принимает команду на отключение вообще этой панели.

[image: картинка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите новый цвет через параметр [`.options.plugins.legend.labels.color = 'COLOR'`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration)

Либо через конфигурацию при инициализации **Chart**'а:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          color: 'red'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Помогло. Я не догадался указать Label при обращении к цвету.

Comment: Мне тоже показалось слишком запарным и не очевидным указывать такой длинный "путь", чтобы внести какие-то настройки)